# Removing items present in one list-of-lists from another in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, set

TL/DR: I'm trying to remove RSS headlines & links that show up in one list-of-lists from another.

I have a widget that pulls Google News RSS headlines + links, and outputs them into a list-of-lists on a daily basis. I am trying to build a function that removes any stories that showed up in the prior day's pull.

My solution transforms the list-of-lists into a DataFrame, compares it against a RSSmemory.csv DataFrame, performs the iteration, then transforms the result back into a list-of-lists. I know my solution is hacked/error-prone and unpythonic. Is there a cleaner way to do it?

The structured of the list-of-lists is:
list_of_headlines = [[headline 1, headline 2],[link 1, link 2]]

If "headline 2, link 2" was in the prior day's pull, I want to remove it from list_of_headlines, to have a unique list of the newest articles.

I listed my code below for reference. Thanks for your insight!

```
list_of_headlines = [['Google new product', 'Youtube app updated'],['http://googl.news/link1','http://googl.news/link2']]
# Put in headlines into a DataFrame to compare it to the headline memory bank
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_headlines)
dft = df.transpose()
# Pull in the memory
dfm = pd.read_csv('\\RSSmemory.csv', sep=",", encoding="utf-8")
# Find the indexes of the old stories in current days headlines
indexes = []
for test in range(0,len(dft)):
    if dfm.ix[:,0].str.contains(dft.ix[test,0]).any():
            indexes.append(test)
    else:
        continue
# Drop the duplicates, reset the index
dft.drop(dft.index[indexes], inplace = True)
dft = dft.reset_index(drop=True)
# Update the memory bank
with open(r'\\RSSmemory.csv', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    dft.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
# Transpose it back, and create list of lists again for the rest of the handling
dftt = dft.transpose()
cleanheadlines = dftt.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have loaded the data, you can use set operations.
If I understand correctly, you have data like this:

```
day1 = [["headline 1"],["link 1"]]
day2 = [["headline 2", "headline 3"],["link 2", "link 3"]]
```

Then you could reduce the data like this:

```
day2 = list(map(list, zip(*set(zip(*day2))-set(zip(*day1)))))
```

The result of the inner operation will be a list of two tuples, instead of two lists. This is why I used map to obtain the two desired lists.

Comment: Tristan, thank you! This is a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I really like @Tristan's answer, but this is an alternative that is quicker under some circumstances but usually not.

```
day1 = [
    ['h{}'.format(i) for i in range(20)],
    ['l{}'.format(i) for i in range(20)]]
day2 = [
    ['h{}'.format(i) for i in range(10, 30)],
    ['l{}'.format(i) for i in range(10, 30)]]

[list(j) for j in 
 zip(*[[h, day2[1][i]] for i, h in enumerate(day2[0]) if h not in day1[0]])]

[['h20', 'h21', 'h22', 'h23', 'h24', 'h25', 'h26', 'h27', 'h28', 'h29'],
 ['l20', 'l21', 'l22', 'l23', 'l24', 'l25', 'l26', 'l27', 'l28', 'l29']]
```

---

***naive time testing***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I ran with Tristan's as I'm a bit more familiar with the syntax